# assertEquals failing on two seemingly identical Strings

Tags: java, junit

Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void testAddPaperConfirm()
{
    String input = "P\n" +
                    "The Life of Geoff the Platypus";
    InputStream testInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(testOutput));
    System.setIn(testInput);
    testReviewSystem.main(new String[] {});
    assertEquals(testOutput.toString(), "What do you want to do?\n" +
            "O = Overview, P = Add Paper, R = Add Review, [num] = Detail of that paper, X = exit\n" +
            "What is the title of the paper?\n" +
            "[Paper added]\n"
            + "What do you want to do?\n" +
            "O = Overview, P = Add Paper, R = Add Review, [num] = Detail of that paper, X = exit\n");
}
```

When I look at the two strings I'm told they're identical. [image]

Comment: Hint: stay away from assertEquals. Simply check out its big brother **assertThat**. That one is typically far better in comparing values and telling you what is not matching.

Comment: Your test is missing some crucial info that would let us try to reproduce the problem.. Can you update to include it?

Comment: Perhaps the actual output uses `\r\n` for newlines?

Comment: @Chris I don't think I can share the code that I'm testing because I didn't write it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're running your tests on windows and it outputs `\r\n` instead of `\n` as line separator. You can try this by changing your assert to the following code.

```
assertEquals(testOutput.toString(), "What do you want to do?\r\n" +
        "O = Overview, P = Add Paper, R = Add Review, [num] = Detail of that paper, X = exit\r\n" +
        "What is the title of the paper?\r\n" +
        "[Paper added]\r\n"
        + "What do you want to do?\r\n" +
        "O = Overview, P = Add Paper, R = Add Review, [num] = Detail of that paper, X = exit\r\n")
```

I've written a test library named [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules) that makes testing command-line applications easier.

```
public class TheTest {
  @Rule
  public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock
    = emptyStandardInputStream();
  @Rule
  public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule
    = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

  @Test
  public void testAddPaperConfirm() {
    systemInMock.provideLines("P", "The Life of Geoff the Platypus");
    testReviewSystem.main(new String[] {});
    String output = systemOutRule.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator();
    assertEquals(output, "What do you want to do?\n" +
        "O = Overview, P = Add Paper, R = Add Review, [num] = Detail of that paper, X = exit\n" +
        "What is the title of the paper?\n" +
        "[Paper added]\n"
        + "What do you want to do?\n" +
        "O = Overview, P = Add Paper, R = Add Review, [num] = Detail of that paper, X = exit\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It is failing because they are not identical.

Two strings that look identical can be diferent. There are many bytes that can't be representated and shown.

For example ascii code 0 and ascii code 1, they'd look identical but they aren't.

http://www.ascii-code.com/